# Conversion of the type of a Template class?

Tags: c#, generics, templates, type-conversion

I have a class named "baseClass".
From this class I inherit a class names "inheritedClass" (public class inheritedClass: baseClass)

The baseClass contains a public function that returns a `HashSet<baseClass>`. When called from the inheritedClass, the return type is obviously still `HashSet<baseClass>`, but I need a `HashSet<inheritedClass>`.

A conversion ala (`HashSet<inheritedClass>`)returnValue, where returnValue is of Type `HashSet<baseClass>` doesn't work.

Is there a way to convert the HashSet-Type from baseClass to inheritedClass without converting each element manually?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: What? (Fifteen character limit)

Comment: You say you want to convert from HashMap to HashMap, but that's the same class. Am I missing here something?

Comment: You were missing the type arguments, which hadn't been quoted :)

Comment: You can do this with a Generic BaseClass, check out my answer..

Comment: Secondly, why do you wnat to add overhead of casting when this can be done using generics.

Comment: I am not used to generics, so the Cast<DerivedTyp>() is a simple solution for my problem. The overhead is no performance problem at the moment. I will have a deeper look into generics in the future, but before that, I refrain from using a technology, which I don't understand good enough. Secondly, I would need to reengineer my existing classes and I have no idea, how much work this would be.

Comment: Let me break you of a bad habit. Generics are not templates. Though they superficially look and act like C++ templates, they are actually very different technologies. I recommend getting out of the habit of calling them templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean C# in the tags? `HashMap` is a Java type. Also it generally has two type parameters rather than one...

In C#, generic classes are always invariant. *Some* interfaces *will* be variant in C# 4, but very few (only those which either *only* use the type parameter in an output positiion, e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`, or *only* use the type parameter in an input position, e.g. `IComparable<T>`).

If you can provide more precise information about your situation, we'll probably be able to help come up with a simple solution - particularly if you can use LINQ with its `Cast<T>()` method.

EDIT: Okay, with `HashSet<T>`:

```
HashSet<BaseType> baseSet = ...;
var derivedSet = new HashSet<DerivedType>(baseSet.Cast<DerivedType>());
```

Note that even with C# 4 this would be necessary because the compiler doesn't know that every value in `baseSet` is an instance of `DerivedType` - there has to be an execution-time check. The reverse (creating a `HashSet<BaseType>` from a `HashSet<DerivedType>`) *would* work in C# 4.

FURTHER EDIT: If you just want to use `UnionWith`, that doesn't require a `HashSet<DerivedType>` - it requires an `IEnumerable<DerivedType>`. I suggest you do:

```
HashSet<BaseType> baseSet = ...;
HashSet<DerivedType> derivedSet = ...;

derivedSet.UnionWith(baseSet.Cast<DerivedType>());
```

Comment: Arr ... I ment HashSet, not HashMap.

From your answer I read, that it is not possible to convert the HashSet-Type and do have to do it manually, right?

What is behind the question: I want to use the Union-method of the HashSet<inheritedType>, so I need to provide a Parameter of the Type HashSet<inheritedType>, but my function returns HashSet<baseType>

Comment: The UnionWith-method, not Union-method

Comment: the Cast<DerivedType>() is what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution

```
//**Your BaseClass**
public class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    public HashSet<T> GetHashSet()
    {
        HashSet<T> _hSet = new HashSet<T>();
        //do some work              
        //create a HashSet<T> and return;              
        return _hSet;
    }
}
//**Your Inherited/Derived Class**
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass<InheritedClass>
{
    //you have the method inherited as you need.}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a where clause to the generic type:
where T : BaseClass

Comment: @Oliver: thanks oliver, I added a proper where clause now. It seems ok now ?